# How to generically create table cell and rows with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I am struggling with iterating over an object containing an array with objects. (and nested ones) I am trying to create a generic Table Component in React so it can be used by many views.

**What did I setup?**

```
tableData.map((prop, key) => {
  return (
    <TableRow key={key}>
      <TableCell className={classes.tableCell} key={key}>
        {prop.number}
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell className={classes.tableCell} key={key}>
        {prop.TableType.max_occupancy}
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell className={classes.tableCell} key={key}>
        {prop.price}
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell className={classes.tableCell} key={key}>
        {prop.TableType.description}
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell className={classes.tableCell} key={key}>
        <Button fullWidth color="primary">
          Remove
        </Button>
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
})
```

**The problem that I am facing right now?**

I can not create the content above in a dynamic way. I am encountering several issues like for example:

- The nested objects logic
- The logic should not clash with other implementations in other pages. (react)

**What would I like to achieve?**

I would like to achieve something that is generic and can be used in a wide range of scenarios and does not clash with other pages where this component is being used.

In the end it should look something like this in a visual way:

[image]

**What data do I have?**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "number": 1,
        "status": true,
        "price": 12,
        "table_type_id": 1,
        "venue_id": 1,
        "TableType": {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "Small Table",
            "max_occupancy": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "number": 2,
        "status": true,
        "price": 2,
        "table_type_id": 2,
        "venue_id": 1,
        "TableType": {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "Medium Table",
            "max_occupancy": 6
        }
    }
]
```

> The Codesandbox directory with the full project:
>   https://codesandbox.io/embed/lwzz4j9mz?autoresize=1&eslint=1
>   The fill we are talking about is located at the Components/Table/Table.jsx. (I have added some dummy data in the comments that needs to be parsed to Table rows and cells)

**Properties that needs be used in the view:**

- number
- price
- id
- TableType

Hopefully someone can come up with a smart idea to help me out with this issue! Cheers for all the help and hopefully we can fix this together.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to add what you tried as a https://codesandbox.io/ link

Comment: @MukeshSoni sure, I'll try to add it now.

Comment: What should be the behaviour when there is nested logic? Is it guaranteed that the nested properties will always be objects or could they be something else for eg arrays?

Comment: As a general point, don't give every component in a list the same key. The purpose of the key property for component lists is to help React differentiate them. That's not gonna work if they're all the same. Specifically, what issues are you facing? You say `The nested objects logic`, what logic? They're just simple key pair objects, so what logic do you mean, accessing their values? Also you said `The logic should not clash with other implementations`, that's gonna be REAL hard for us to help with when we don't have any context of the rest of the app

Comment: I'd use a third party like `react-table` https://github.com/react-tools/react-table

Comment: Guys hang on I am trying to add some stuff to codesanbox!

Comment: @ShyamBabu  have added the full project to codesandbox for you guys!

Comment: @Jayce444 I have added the full project to codesandbox for you!

Comment: @t3__rry I have added the full project to codesandbox for you!

Comment: Is your request to make it more DRY and for a way for the parent of table to specify how to access each data in each cell rather than hard coding it?

Comment: @ShyamBabu I want to make the Table Component to be more reusable by other components. So yes, I would like to make it more DRY. Also I want to make it more dynamic. Now I repeat myself 3.4 times to create a table row and cell.

Comment: The sandbox example takes me to login screen for all tabs. What's the username/password?

Comment: @MukeshSoni it's not a working. It should be connected with local API.

Comment: You should try and express your problem only in terms of the structure of data and that one component in the sandbox. Not the whole app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use an external library to get this done. But if you want to go for an in house approach this would be one way to go about it.

To the component, send the data and the header.The header should also specify how the data should be parsed to receive it's value.

```js
var defaultTemaplate = '<TableRow><TableCell style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Woooops! You haven\'t applied any tables for this venue yet. To start renting out tables you should add at least 3 tables tothe app. Just press the button above to start imediately.</TableCell></TableRow>'
var tableHead = [{
    title: 'number',
    type: 'data',
    path: 'number'
  },
  {
    title: 'TableType',
    type: 'data',
    path: 'TableType.description'
  },
  {
    title: 'Edit/delete',
    type: 'template',
    templateString: '<button></button>'
  }
] //for all columns
var tableData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "number": 1,
    "status": true,
    "price": 12,
    "table_type_id": 1,
    "venue_id": 1,
    "TableType": {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "Small Table",
      "max_occupancy": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "number": 2,
    "status": true,
    "price": 2,
    "table_type_id": 2,
    "venue_id": 1,
    "TableType": {
      "id": 2,
      "description": "Medium Table",
      "max_occupancy": 6
    }
  }
]
console.log(genRows(tableData))

function getTableCells(data) {
  return tableHead.map((opts) => {
    if (opts.type === 'data') {
      return `<TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>${_.at(data, opts.path)}</TableCell>`
    }
    if (opts.type === 'template') {
      return opts.templateString
    }
  })
}

function genRows(tableData) {
  if (tableData.length < 0) return defaultTemaplate;
  return tableData.map((rowData) => `<TableRow>${getTableCells(rowData)}</TableRow>`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

This is just an example to demonstrate one approach you could take, not full fledged code and can defenetly be improved.

Comment: It thrown an error undefined for the path property when an array is given.

Comment: That was not a fully tested code. it was just a minimal code to show an approach you could take let me correct it.

Comment: Ahhh I see, sorry about that! Would you mind to have a look over it? This is giving me a very good direction but I am still stuck. I'll accept the answer then! :) Thanks a lot in advance sir

Comment: it looks like the map function is changing the type: template to type data automagically

Comment: It was classic messup of === with = :P. Ive corrected it now. Adapting it to react is upto you ;)

Comment: I am receiving the following issue: VM1414 bundle.js:3472 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, type, templateString}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: This line is just returning a number and not the data that I expected: path.reduce((obj, path) => obj[path], data); -> for the nested key value pairs at least

Comment: You can replace it with lodash _at_ or ramda's _paths_ if use any of those libs

Comment: Could you update your answer with a working example from the pastie and some comments? Ill accept the answer soon

Comment: Fixed it by changing the table header as well! Thanks brother <3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170222/discussion-between-kevin-vugts-and-shyam-babu).